# Using selected listbox value to dynamically hide/show columns

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, controls, userform

I could use some help with a multi-select listbox form in excel which has to be done via VBA, the values of the forms are months from jan-june as seen below.

- JAN
- FEB
- MARCH
- APRIL
- MAY
- JUNE

If Jan is selected for example , I would like columns , e through h shown. 
If Jan is not selected then columns e through h would be hidden.

JAN - (COLUMNS E-H)
FEB - (COLUMNS I-M)
MARCH - (COLUMNS N-R)
APRIL - (COLUMNS S-W)
MAY - (COLUMNS X-AB)
JUNE - (COLUMNS AC-AG)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Sometimes, the macro recorder is your friend.

I recorded a macro of myself hiding columns E through H. Here was the recorded code:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
' Macro recorded 7/17/2012 by Jimmy Peña
'

'
    Columns("E:H").Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End Sub
```

The Select/Selection pair is a clear indication that I can concatenate these two lines. I shorten the code like this:

`Columns("E:H").EntireColumn.Hidden = True`

Since the property takes a value of `True`, I know that I can hide columns by setting the value to `True` and show columns by setting the value to `False`.

Since you haven't shown the code you are using, I'll provide a generic approach which you will need to customize for your use.

I added a listbox to a sample userform. This code will selectively hide/unhide depending on which value is selected.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()

  Dim selectedValue As String

  ' get selected value from listbox
  selectedValue = ListBox1.value

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  ' unhide any columns
  Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

  Select Case selectedValue
  Case "JAN"
    Columns("E:H").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
  Case "FEB"
    Columns("I:M").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
  Case "MARCH"
    Columns("N:R").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
  Case "APRIL"
    Columns("S:W").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
  Case "MAY"
    Columns("X:AB").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
  Case "JUNE"
    Columns("AC:AG").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
  End Select

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Does your solution use a normal form control or an activex form control

Comment: @user1422641 This is a Listbox on a VBA userform, but should not take much adapting to use with any other type of Listbox control.